# Optimization while mixing c style strings with c++ strings

Tags: c++, c, string, optimization, c-strings

I was trying to solve a programming problem from a website and got time limit exceed. Now I'm trying to change some parts of my code where I use C++ string to C style strings.

Here is a part from my code that I wanted some advice:

```
    x1 = X1 + X2 + X3;
    x2 = X1 + X3 + X2;
    x3 = X2 + X1 + X3;
    x4 = X2 + X3 + X1;
    x5 = X3 + X2 + X1;
    x6 = X3 + X1 + X2;
```

Before, all of those variables above were C++ strings, now I have changed the uppercase ones to C-style, so those assignments are no longer valid...

What would be the fastest way to initialize the lower-case ones?

```
x1 = X1; 
x1 += X2; 
x1 += X3;
```

or

```
char buffer[20]; //would use x1 instead of a buffer if the answer to the second question 
                 //is to convert it(x1) to C-style
strcpy(buffer, X1); 
strcat(buffer, X2); 
strcat(buffer, X3); 
x1 = buffer;
```

the only use for the lowercase ones is in this comparison:

```
if(current == x1 || current == x2 || current == x3 || current == x4 || current == x5 || current == x6)
```

where 'current' is C++ string (And this one I won't change because I'm updating its value through elements inside a container)

this IF is going to be executed MANY times, so I want to know if it is better to let x1 ... x6 as C++ strings (I suppose if I compare C++ string with a C-style string it will call a constructor from C++ string and pass the C-style as argument before the comparison).

EDIT:

Reformulating: I what I want to know in the second is:

When I make a comparison like this:

```
string st = "something";
char st2[20] = "other thing";
if(st == st2)
```

Is it going to call the constructor string(st2) and the compare constructed string to the one at the left? Lets say I do this comparison 500000x, would it be faster if st2 were already a C++ string?

EDIT2: The complete code is [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/54995/optimization-while-mixing-c-style-strings-with-c-strings)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Don't assume that C strings are going to be any faster than C++ strings just because. It all comes down to your algorithms, namely avoiding copying.  Anyway, use `strcmp` for comparing C strings.

Comment: It is simple. C doesn't support operator overloading, hence wherever you have used strings with `+` or `==` operator, you will have to replace with `strcat/strcpy` and `strcmp` respectively.

Comment: If you post more of your relevant code, it will be helpful.

Comment: I know man, my question wasn't just that... the thing is: This code is for a BFS and the maximum number of nodes in the graph is 511920... I'm using the strings in a queue and a set(to know who was already visited)... but the part that is not using the set and the queue I can change to C

Comment: @RSahu I use almost always only C-style, needed C++ type to make easier the manipulation of containers... like I said: the main question is in that IF, lets say it is going to be executed 511920, I'm asking if it is faster keeping a C++ string while comparing... what I mean is: If I let a comparison between C++ strig with a C-style... will I be calling 6x string constructor for each of those 511920 comparisons?

Comment: The standard library provides `operator ==` overloads that takes a `std::string` and a C-style string.

Comment: @nightshade, comparing C-style strings or `std:string` won't make or break your code. The only place where I would be concerned about performance is creation of temporary `std::string`s. If you can minimize that by judicious use of C-style strings, you should be OK.

Comment: @RSahu, thats what I'm concerned about... I don't know how that comparison is made.. if that comparison has to create a constructor or if the C++ string can be treated as C-style string (without needing any conversion)

Comment: @nightshade, Unless you can post more code, it's hard to suggest anything valuable.

Comment: @T.C. I know the operator is overloaded... I just don't know what happens in the black box... Is it making a new C++ string from the C-style string or does he C++ string have a similar representation that can be compared to a C-style without calling any constructor or method to convert... (I don't know what happens internally in that comparison due to its encapsulation)

Comment: I would profile before assuming something was causing the slowness.

Comment: @RSahu It is because my whole program is 390 lines of code and this part is what I thought to be one of the most relevant (the other is the vector<string> and set<string> that might be causing some slow when I call clear method, since the documentation says it is linear in the number of elements)

Comment: Perhaps you should post your full code at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @nightshade That's entirely implementation-dependent. I would be very surprised if they created a temporary string just for comparison though.

Comment: just created accoutn there, how do I upload? Do I click ask question and just pasted my code ? @RSahu

Comment: @nightshade, AFAIK, it works just like SO. You post your code by copy and paste from your files.

Comment: @RSahu I posted the code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want speed, don't create a string just in order to do a comparison; especially, don't create six strings since you might sometimes only need one or two of them. It's not relevant whether they are C strings or C++ strings.

Do you know how long `X1`, `X2` and `X3` are? It's easy enough to find out, if not. Assuming you do, what you want to know is something like:

```
if (   current.compare(0, lenX1, X1) == 0 &&
       (   current.compare(lenX1, lenX2, X2) == 0
           && current.compare(lenX1+lenX2, lenX3, X3) == 0 
        || current.compare(lenX1, lenX3, X3) == 0
           && current.compare(lenX1+lenX3, lenX2, X2) == 0)
    || current.compare(0, lenX2, X2) == 0 &&
       (   current.compare(lenX2, lenX1, X1) == 0
           && current.compare(lenX2+lenX1, lenX3, X3) == 0
        || current.compare(lenX2, lenX3, X3) == 0
           && current.compare(lenX2+lenX3, lenX1, X1) == 0)
    || current.compare(0, lenX3, X3) == 0 &&
       (   current.compare(lenX3, lenX1, X1) == 0
           && current.compare(lenX3+lenX1, lenX2, X2) == 0
        || current.compare(lenX3, lenX2, X2) == 0
           && current.compare(lenX3+lenX2, lenX1, X1) == 0))
```

Your version is more readable, of course, and mine might have typos.

I suspect that this, too, is unnecessary; you need to reexamine your design. Why are you using concatenated strings instead of, for example, tuples of small integers?

Comment: It is a graph problem, I'm keeping track of 3 robots in a grid at most 9x9... X1, X2, X3 are the coordinates where the robots must arrive (each one has to arrive in one, doesn't matter who arrive in each)... Since doesn't matter who arrive in each goal (as long as all of them arrive in a goal at the same time) I'm using those x1...x6 to be the permutations that they might have arrived (x1 means R1 arrived in G1, R2 in G2, R3 in G3, R = robot, G = goal)

Comment: @nightshade: I'm certain you have better options than strings for that.

Comment: I thought about pairs for each robot and then put the 3 pairs inside a set (after wrap them with something) but then I had the idea of putting the strings that would be a concatenation (I thought about giving a different magnitude for each robot coordinate but if some of them happen to be 0 then I might have repeated values for different positions)... The website doesn't use C++ 11 so I didn't even check how to use tuples @rici

Comment: Well, guess this compare method makes clear that there is no creating of a new string while doing it... thanks